# Node.js TCP server that eval and print data

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, eval

I try to create simple TCP server that eval and print the result, but It didn't work, here is my code:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        socket.write('result: ');
        socket.end(eval(data));
    });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

When I connect to port 8080 I got this:

```
$ echo 10+10 | nc localhost 8080
result: 10+10
```

Why eval don't work?

Comment: Does `socket.write('result: ' + eval(data)); socket.end();` work?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand No, it don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a stream receives a `Buffer` object on data events.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

> If the argument of eval() is not a string, eval() returns the argument unchanged

Since `eval`uating an object has no effect, `write()` sent the data as is. You must explicitly set the encoding of the socket to **utf8** for data to be converted to a string.

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.setEncoding('utf8');
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        socket.write('result: ');
        var evaluatedData = eval(data);
        socket.end(evaluatedData.toString());
    });
});
```

`toString()` is required because `socket.write`, actually `Writable.write`, accepts a `string` or `Buffer`.

Comment: Got the same result, but when I write `typeof data` it got object not string. I try `data.toString()` but got error `First argument must be a buffer or a string.`

Comment: You explain it right but your code is wrong, it should be `eval(data.toString())` in my example I need to get result to string too because I got a number from eval. So the solution is `socket.end(eval(data.toString()).toString());`

Comment: @jcubic, bro, I think you didn't set the encoding to utf8. You wouldn't need to do `toString` on data if the encoding is utf8.